# Facebook Secure Canvas URL with GAE and GWT

Tags: facebook, google-app-engine, gwt, https

I developed a game running in facebook using GWT and Google app engine.
following facebook new rule to supply secure canvas url, I am no longer able to run my application.

Does someone know What are the changes I should do to my application?

Thanks a lot
Shahar.

Comment: can you link to this new rule, or explain what it is?  what do you mean when you say "I am no longer able to run my application" - what happens when you do?

Answer (score 0):

You can use https if you use the app-id.appspot.com domain instead of your custom domain.

Google has informed that it will start supporting https in custom domains but it is in test phase.

Ps: I have my canvas+page tab app workin with https.